# Adding a password prompt when accessing specified FlowRouter routes

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm currently trying to implement a flowrouter trigger function that stops the current route and prompts you for a pin.

Once the pin is provided, this is checked and if correct; the user will continue to their requested route.

I've included my Flow router route, enter trigger function and the pin prompt function below:

The stop event on the router works fine.
The pin capture function also works no problem.
Grabbing the requested path on success also works however when this is pushed into FlowRouter.go(); the URL changes however the app doesn't follow the route.

```
// Flow Router route

StaffRoutes.route('/browse', {
    name: "browseAccounts",
    triggersEnter: [enterPin],
    action: function() {
        BlazeLayout.render('cardLayout', {
            main: "browseSearch"
        })
    }
});



// Enter PIN code trigger function

function enterPin(context, redirect, stop) {
    // saving the requested route for after pin login success
    let route = FlowRouter.current();
    Session.set('redirectAfterPin', route.path);

    // this just shows a hidden pin pad
    showPinPrompt();

    // stopping the current route
    stop();
}

// pinPromptSubmission
function pinSubmission() {
    // presume pin is correct
    if (pinIsCorrect) {

        // grab requested path and initiate FlowRouter go
        let newPath = Session.get('redirectAfterPin');
        FlowRouter.go(newPath);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows why this isn't working, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: it looks ok. what is not working? showing the pin prompt or the redirection after pin entry.

Comment: Once the pin is entered, the URL path changes however the DOM isn't changed and remains on the current template. (sorry for the late reply, I was taking a vacation!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code looks similar. Instead of find the path using FlowRouter.current, I use context.path. Instead of using stop(), I use redirect(). Here is my code.

```
FlowRouter.route("/loans/apply", {
  name: "loanApplication",
  action(params) {
    renderLayoutWith(<LoanApplicationContainer />, "Apply Loan");
  },
  triggersEnter: [redirectAnonymous]
});

function redirectAnonymous(context, redirect) {
  if(!Meteor.userId()) {
    redirect('/login?redirectUrl=' + context.path);
  }
}
```